# Can anyone suggest disadvantages to production use of a database embedded in a servlet container?

Tags: database, tomcat, derby, embedded-database

Specifically, my team is considering embedding Apache Derby in Tomcat as part of a production deployment, with ease of deployment being the primary motivation. Can anyone suggest any significant disadvantages to this plan? The database will be accessed by two, or potentially three, web apps simultaneously. Initially, the highest number of entries in any one table is predicted to be around the 10,000 mark, though this may increase. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like an ideal use of Derby to me! Derby is designed to be embedded, and to be easily deployed. The only thing that's a bit complex is the use of multiple web apps. Since each Tomcat web app is a separate class loader instance, they look like multiple independent client apps to Derby, so you'll need to use the Derby client/server connection protocols rather than the Derby embedded protocols when connecting. That is, to use the terminology of http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/devguide/cdevdvlp96597.html, each Tomcat web app is a separate Derby instance.

In your configuration, you might find it useful to use 'derby.war', the Derby network server packaged as a WAR file. Package that WAR into your Tomcat instance as yet another web app, and use it to manage the Derby server code, then have each of your client web apps connect to it.
See http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/adminguide/cadminservlet98430.html

Comment: Thanks, Bryan, we may well go with the derby.war approach. We were considering defining the datasource at the server level and accessing it via JNDI lookup, in the manner described here: http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/DerbyTomcat5512JPetStor.html How would you rate that approach?

Comment: I think that's a fine approach. The most important point of the JPetStore configuration, though, is that their application is packaged as a single Tomcat web app. In your original message you specifically mentioned "two, or potentially three, web apps simultaneously". If you can keep it to a single web app which accesses Derby, then by all means use the embedded configuration, as it's substantially simpler than the client-server configuration.